# I cannot have similar router paths in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm just learning Vue3 and trying to do some routing, but I'm getting an error message that makes no sense.
Maybe it's related to some kind of `nested routing`, but I also tried to do `children` and it didn't want to work.

This works:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HomePage from '../home/HomePage.vue';
import FetchAccount from '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/FetchAccount.vue';
import CreateADAccount from '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/CreateADAccount.vue';

export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: HomePage,
    },
    {
      path: '/FetchAccount',
      name: 'FetchAccount',
      component: FetchAccount,
    },
    {
      path: '/CreateADAccount',
      name: 'CreateADAccount',
      component: CreateADAccount,
    },
  ],
});
```

And this does not:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HomePage from '../home/HomePage.vue';
import FetchAccount from '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/FetchAccount.vue';
import CreateADAccount from '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/CreateADAccount.vue';

export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: HomePage,
    },
    {
      path: '/NonPrimaryADAccount/FetchAccount',
      name: 'FetchAccount',
      component: FetchAccount,
    },
    {
      path: '/NonPrimaryADAccount/CreateADAccount',
      name: 'CreateADAccount',
      component: CreateADAccount,
    },
  ],
});
```

Error message:

```
4:29  error  Unable to resolve path to module '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/CreateADAccount.vue'  import/no-unresolved
```

Comment: It doesn't have to do with routes, it cannot find this path : import CreateADAccount from '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/CreateADAccount.vue';

Comment: Right, but for example, if I remove "/NonPrimaryADAccount/" leaving only "path: '/FetchAccount'", then the code is working.
That's why I cannot really wrap my head around it.

Comment: check if file exist in '../nonPrimaryADAccounts/CreateADAccount.vue'; It says `Unable to resolve path to module` so import is not working. Line 4

Comment: You also have problems with naming convetions, https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide/#single-file-component-filename-casing-strongly-recommended

Comment: The file is there, no problem with that.
Regarding naming convention - I'll look into it, but right now, I cannot fix the damn routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need nested path the recommended approach is to use a function to generate the routes with the prefix:

```
const withPrefix = (prefix, routes) => 
    routes.map( (route) => {
        route.path = prefix + route.path;
        return route;
    });

export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: HomePage,
    },
    ...withPrefix('/NonPrimaryADAccount',[
        { 
          path: '/FetchData',
          name: 'FetchData',
          component: FetchData,
        },
        { 
          path: '/CreateADAccount',
          name: 'CreateADAccount',
          component: CreateADAccount,
        },
    ]),
]
```

Comment: Why doesn’t OPs code work?

Comment: @Chin. Udara hey mate , error message tells why, there is no route. To render components into this nested routes, we need to use the children option

Comment: So here's the version with the children option:
https://pastebin.com/xGAMuSP7

But it's still giving an error message.
Jeez, at this point I don't know what's dumber me or the framework

Comment: Ah, sorry mate, (didn't see empty parent component) take a look now I updated answer